# Which connector do I need for a "line level" subwoofer?

Tags: audio, connection, speakers

I've got a separate pair of speakers and I'm looking at adding a subwoofer ([this, specifically](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16882290034)). I noticed on the detail page it's inputs are listed as such:

> Inputs: Speaker level, line level

If I'm not mistaken "line level" are the standard 3.5 audio jacks on your motherboard/sound card, right? I looked up [the connector colors/names on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports) and confirmed what line level is but I'm less sure about the additional "speaker level" bit.

My motherboard has the standard 6 ports for sound, if I get a subwoofer like this can I simply plug the input into the orange 3.5 jack? My audio software supports up to 7.1 so software-wise, 2.1 wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Line level" defined the signal level not the connector.

Although 3.5mm TRS connectors (mini-jack) can carry line-level signals, that does not exclude other connector types (such as RCA) from also carrying line level signals.

If you look at the [PSW10 manual](http://www.polkaudio.com/downloads/manual/PSW10_12_MN.pdf) you can see that the line level input is an RCA connector, and since the Wikipedia page you linked to confirms that a computer´s "orange 3.5mm TRS" connector should be line level you can connect your PC to the subwoofer using a Mini-Jack to RCA cable.

Answer (score 1):

Line level is a low voltage signal, typically between 1v-5v. Speaker level is an alreadly amplified signal that can be passed directly to a speaker. 3.5mm jacks typically output a pre-amplified signal(speaker level) that can be listened to through headphones or speakers. A line-level singal is too low to be listend to directly(though you could try), because it does not have enough power to drive a large speaker.

Typically, the sub woofer doesn't care what the signal is. If it is a speaker level signal, you will need to turn the gain down on the sub amplifier to stop it from playing to loud. If it is line level, then you will need to turn the gain up on the amplifier to match your speaker levels. Line level is typically 'cleaner' sound thatn speaker level, because amps introduce noise that isn't present in a line level signal. Amping an already amplified signal increase the level of the original noise, as well as adds more to it.

One thing to note, there really isn't much risk of damaging equipment here if you experiment at a low volume.

Comment: So it'll work with the standard inputs, just test it out at a low volume?

Comment: It should, and the subwoofer should have a level knob on it to turn it up and down. If not, within your software there should be a level adjustment. Turn the signal comng out of the computer all the way down and plug it it. Turn on some music and slowly increase it until its where you would like. It make take a few rounds of this before you get it perfect, espcecially if your subwoofer has an adjust knob of its own.